# How to model voting for different object types in your data model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I've got several objects that I want my users be to be able to up / down vote.  (similar to SO questions)  If it was just a single object type, I could just have a simple one to many relationship, but I have at least three object types that need vote tracking.

I'm using MVC3 and EF CodeFirst.

Here is a first draft

> ```
> public class Deed
> {
>     public int DeedId { get; set; }
>     [Required]
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public string Description { get; set; }
>     public virtual ICollection<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
> }
> ```

```
public class Vote
{
    public int VoteId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }  // +1, -1
    public ItemType VoteType { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
}

public enum ItemType
{
    DEED,
    ACTIVITY,
    IDEA
}
```

What kinda trouble am I going to run into with this?  An alternative could be to keep the votes table completely unrelated to the other entities and use a repository to populate a VoteTotal field on Deed, Activity, and Idea objects.

Comment: Have you tried using inheritance and making votes have a relation with the toplevel type? e.g. Deed, Activity and Idea could all inherit from Item, which have a one-to-many relationship with votes. (You should be able to use inheritance with EF)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a base class for example "VotableObject", Deed, Activity and Idea would inherit from that object.

The voting would be connected to the base class.

Comment: Decent idea, but I'm hesitant to use inheritance here.  Certainly, a "Deed" is a "VotableObject" so inheritance seems viable.  But that's like having all of the products on a website inherit from "PurchasableObject".  That still doesn't feel right.   I think I'm looking for some type of composition pattern.